# First Button(radio) is always on

Tags: java, swt

I am building a game scoring system where two teams play hands. There is a winner for each hand, however the winner is unknown until the hand is played. I show who wins by clicking on a radio button. If a team's radio button is "clicked" then I programmatically "unclick" the other button. I am only showing a single hand below, but you can have more than one hand and they are added below the first hand (programmatically add another composite **b** and its groups).

**Note**: Second and subsequent hands *do* have both radio buttons turned off upon creation.

The problem is that the very first radio button created (left group), is ALWAYS selected on, and I cannot turn it off. If I click on winner in the right panel, then I can turn off the winner in the left panel under program control and vice-versa.

But I cannot **START** with both buttons turned off.

It appears that SWT somewhere in the background turns on the first radio button created in a form and WILL NOT let it be turned off, unless another radio button somewhere else in the form has been turned on, irrespective of layering or radio-grouping. I have tested this by turning on the last radio button in the form, and sure enough I can turn off the first radio button.

The creation code for all the radio buttons/ The groups are created with `SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP`:

```
ivWinHandRadio = new Button( group, SWT.RADIO | SWT.RIGHT );
ivWinHandRadio.setText( "Winner!" );
```

The switch code is

```
void setWinOff()
{
   ivWinHandRadio.setSelection( false );
   ivWinHandRadio.notifyListeners( SWT.Selection, new Event() );
}
```

I have the SWT layered as:

```
a|------------------------------------------------|
b||----------------------------------------------||
c|||=====================||=====================|||
d||| ( ) Winner!         ||   ( ) Winner!       |||
 |||                     ||                     |||
 |||=====================||=====================|||
 ||----------------------------------------------||
 |------------------------------------------------|
```

- **a** is a scrolling composite
- **b** is a composite
- **c** are two groups
- **d** is a radio button in each group

How do I make both radio buttons off when I create them? It's not good showing the left side as being a winner before the hand is played.

Note: I COULD turn on the last radio button in the form, then turn off the first button. Then on the first radio click I could turn off the last radio button, and therefore kludge around the issue. I have tested this. Bleah!

Comment: Both buttons appear off when I try and reproduce you code here. In any case Radio buttons don't seem to be the right choice here. Checkbox (SWT.CHECK) would seem to be more appropriate. Since there is only one radio button in each group SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP has no effect.

Comment: Yes, I could toggle a checkbox. But a radio seems more appropriate as the logic is one-of rather than either or both. I tried several ways of creating the radio buttons, but always had one turned on by some underlying process.